# which is the best way for adding maintenance mode in laravel?

Tags: laravel, performance, laravel-blade, laravel-middleware

i want to add maintenance mode to my cms which i built with laravel,
i want to add front part of it, but i don't know which is the best place for checking maintenance mode, in my basic layout file or in a middleware or somewhere else.

consider it that this check should be run on each request on my frontend routes, therefor it needed to be super optimized.

please remind that i want to enable this capability on admin panel of cms, so the admin user doesn't has permission on built in laravel maintenance mode.

and i want it to be okay with a shared host environment. (i have no access to shell commands)

any idea?

i tried to put it on my blade file and in a middleware, but i think it's not optimized.

Comment: Laravel already provides maintenance mode (docs https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/configuration#maintenance-mode)

Comment: yeah, but i provided this feature in my cms, thus admin can turn this feature on or off from admin panel which i designed in setting part of cms. and remind that he doesn't has access to laravel features on there!

Comment: If the CMS is on the same server you could use something like [shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) to call the command. If not you can add an endpoint on Laravel and call that

Comment: yes, but i want it to be okay with a shared host environment. (no access to shell commandes)

Comment: no in that case you'd probably add a route on Laravel that calls that command programmatically (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands). Just be sure to set maintenance mode with a secret and use the same secret to turn it off otherwise you won't be able to

Answer (score 0):

You could add a Middleware to the Front end routes only. When someone enables maintenance mode in the admin area the middleware could check if maintenance mode is enabled and redirect or show a view

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class MaintenanceMode
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (/** Logic Here **/) {
            // Show a diff page
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems to be the best answer! thanks